# Fragments with custom list adapter causing crash on inflate view

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments, inflate

I am attempting to convert one of my apps to use Fragments to improve how the app looks and works on ICS / Honeycomb but I've come across a problem which although I've spent many hours Googleing and reading answers on here I can't seem to find a fix for.

I have a custom list adapter which is used to display some info I get from an SQLite db. It worked fine before I tried to convert to fragments when it was being displayed in an activity.

However when I try and put the ListView into a fragment the app FC with the following error:

```
W/dalvikvm(  540): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4
09951f8)
E/AndroidRuntime(  540): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(  540): java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(  540):        at com.msi.shortwave.FreqAdaptor.getView(FreqAda
ptor.java:43)
E/AndroidRuntime(  540):        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsList
View.java:2033)
E/AndroidRuntime(  540):        at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListVi
ew.java:1772)
E/AndroidRuntime(  540):        at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.jav
a:672)
E/AndroidRuntime(  540):        at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.
java:732)
E/AndroidRuntime(  540):        at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListVi
ew.java:1625)
E/AndroidRuntime(  540):        at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListVi
ew.java:1863)
E/AndroidRuntime(  540):        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11158)
E/AndroidRuntime(  540):        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:
4197)
E/AndroidRuntime(  540):        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(Lin
earLayout.java:1628)
E/AndroidRuntime(  540):        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(Li
nearLayout.java:1486)
E/AndroidRuntime(  540):        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLa
yout.java:1399)
E/AndroidRuntime(  540):        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11158)
E/AndroidRuntime(  540):        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:
4197)
E/AndroidRuntime(  540):        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(Lin
earLayout.java:1628)
E/AndroidRuntime(  540):        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutHorizontal(
LinearLayout.java:1617)
E/AndroidRuntime(  540):        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLa
yout.java:1401)
E/AndroidRuntime(  540):        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11158)
E/AndroidRuntime(  540):        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:
4197)
E/AndroidRuntime(  540):        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(Lin
earLayout.java:1628)
E/AndroidRuntime(  540):        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(Li
nearLayout.java:1486)
E/AndroidRuntime(  540):        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLa
yout.java:1399)
E/AndroidRuntime(  540):        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11158)
E/AndroidRuntime(  540):        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:
4197)
E/AndroidRuntime(  540):        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayo
ut.java:431)
E/AndroidRuntime(  540):        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11158)
E/AndroidRuntime(  540):        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:
4197)
E/AndroidRuntime(  540):        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(Lin
earLayout.java:1628)
E/AndroidRuntime(  540):        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(Li
nearLayout.java:1486)
E/AndroidRuntime(  540):        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLa
yout.java:1399)
E/AndroidRuntime(  540):        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11158)
E/AndroidRuntime(  540):        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:
4197)
E/AndroidRuntime(  540):        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayo
ut.java:431)
E/AndroidRuntime(  540):        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11158)
E/AndroidRuntime(  540):        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:
4197)
E/AndroidRuntime(  540):        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(V
iewRootImpl.java:1462)
E/AndroidRuntime(  540):        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewR
ootImpl.java:2382)
E/AndroidRuntime(  540):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.ja
va:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(  540):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime(  540):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThrea
d.java:4340)
E/AndroidRuntime(  540):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native
Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(  540):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:5
11)
E/AndroidRuntime(  540):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndA
rgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
E/AndroidRuntime(  540):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(Zygot
eInit.java:551)
E/AndroidRuntime(  540):        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

W/ActivityManager(   84):   Force finishing activity com.msi.shortwave/.main
```

The fragment (results.xml) layout is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<ListView android:id="@+id/ListView01" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"></ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

My row.xml file used by the custom list adaptor is as follows (android:text entries are just placeholders, this is replaced by the app for stuff like the station name)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:paddingLeft="10sp" android:paddingRight="10sp"
android:layout_height="20dp"
android:orientation="vertical" android:paddingTop="2sp">
<TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/tvStationname"
    android:text="BBC World Service" android:typeface="sans" android:textSize="16sp" android:textColor="#990200" android:textStyle="bold"></TextView>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView01" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="Start:" android:textSize="13sp" android:textColor="#000000" android:paddingRight="5sp"></TextView>
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="00:00" android:textColor="#000000" 
        android:id="@+id/tvStarttime" android:textSize="13sp"
        ></TextView>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView02" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textStyle="bold" android:textColor="#000000" 
        android:text="End:" android:textSize="13sp" android:paddingLeft="5sp" android:paddingRight="5sp"></TextView>
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="01:00" android:textColor="#000000" 
        android:id="@+id/tvEndtime" android:textSize="13sp"></TextView>
            <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView03" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="Target Area:" android:textSize="13sp" android:textColor="#000000" 
        android:paddingLeft="5sp" android:paddingRight="5sp"></TextView>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/tvTarget" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textColor="#000000" 
        android:text="LA, NA" android:textSize="13sp"></TextView>
</LinearLayout> 
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView01" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textStyle="bold" android:textColor="#000000" 
        android:text="Frequencies " android:textSize="13sp"></TextView>
        <HorizontalScrollView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:scrollbars ="none"
>

    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="12312, 12314, 14131, 12312"
        android:id="@+id/tvFreqs" android:textColor="#000000"  android:textSize="13sp" android:layout_weight="1" android:singleLine="true" ></TextView>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
        </LinearLayout>
```

My list adapter is called by

```
list = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

The code in my customlistview is FreqAdaptor.java - the crash is in "public View getView" and is shown by comments:

```
package com.msi.shortwave;

import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class FreqAdaptor extends BaseAdapter implements OnClickListener {
private Context context;
private LayoutInflater inflate;

private List<Freqlist> listFreq;

public FreqAdaptor(Context context, List<Freqlist> listFreq, LayoutInflater inflate) {
    this.context = context;
    this.listFreq = listFreq;
    this.inflate = inflate;
}

public int getCount() {
    return listFreq.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return listFreq.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    Freqlist entry = listFreq.get(position);
    if (convertView == null) {

        convertView = inflate.inflate(R.layout.row, null);

//crash is here. inflate is the one used by the view on my results.java file.
// I have also tried with   LayoutInflater inflate = (LayoutInflater) context
  //              .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);  but I get the
//same result

    }
    TextView tvStationname = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvStationname);
    tvStationname.setText(entry.getStationname());

    TextView tvStarttime = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvStarttime);
    tvStarttime.setText(entry.getStarttime());

    TextView tvEndtime = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvEndtime);
    tvEndtime.setText(entry.getEndtime());

    TextView tvTarget = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvTarget);
    tvTarget.setText(entry.getTargets());

    TextView tvFreqs = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvFreqs);
    tvFreqs.setText(entry.getFreqs());


    return convertView;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    Freqlist entry = (Freqlist) view.getTag();


}


}
```

My results.java file starts with the following. As mentioned I have tried using the same inflater for my FreqAdaptor.java and have tried making a new inflater but I get the same crash.

```
   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      // Inflate the layout for this fragment
     v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.results, container, false);
      Bundle bund1 = getArguments();
      passinflate = inflater;
      String time = bund1.getString("time");
        String target = bund1.getString("target");
        String station = bund1.getString("station");
        String freq = bund1.getString("freq");
        new searchdb().execute(time,target,station,freq);

          return v;

   }
```

Can anyone help? As I mention this works fine without using Fragments. App is here https://market.android.com/details?id=com.msi.shortwave and I can provide the full source if anyone needs that to provide me with some suggestions as I really am stuck with it.

Some of my indentation has been messed up by posting using [code] sections above. Not sure why.

EDIT - Do my XML files look OK? I've even changed to a ListFragment and used the xml file here for my fragment- developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html but the same thing keeps happening. Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: on first look i find that u have given id to listview in a wron way(u have given android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01").Change it to android:id="@android:id/list"

Comment: The <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"> in row.xml isnt the listview itself but is a the row of the listview. The code I used for the custom listview was modified from http://code.google.com/p/myandroidwidgets/source/browse/trunk/Phonebook/src/com/abeanie/?r=18

Comment: The way your exception looks the only thing that *can* crash, if it indeed crashes at `inflate.inflate(R.layout.row, null)`, is that `inflate` is `null`. Are you sure that it isn't one of your `findViewById(..)` calls that mess up? BTW. Use ViewHolder pattern ffs.

Comment: I don't think its a findViewById which is doing it as the same code works without using fragments just fine. I will look into Viewholder. I dont think inflate is null either as i've passed it over from the fragment .class file after it has inflated the results.xml file - is that right or wrong?

Comment: And yes the crash definatly happens at that line. Even if I use LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); it still crashes at that line.

Comment: Do my XML files look OK? I've even changed to a ListFragment and used the xml file here for my fragment- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html but the same thing keeps happening. Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

When we are using ListView With Fragment and **there is no error for ids ,ViewHolder or inflater**
but still we are getting Null pionter or etc. Exception then we need to check Fragment Life Cycle-means when and where we are setting our adapter in Fragment, sometimes if we setting our list adapter at onCreateView()  there is chance to not calling listAdapter so, call/set list adapter at onActivityCreated()(When Activity created()).